# Would I be faster using Osmosis to generate smaller .osm files from PostGIS or directly from a larger .osm file?

Tags: openstreetmap, postgis, osmosis

I am currently taking the great-britain-latest.osm file from https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html and importing it into POSTGIS for use with Nominatim.

However I would also like to render mapping tiles using Maperative which cannot handle the size of the entire great-britain file. Therefore my intention is to split the area into smaller .osm file chunks and process these.

My understanding is that Osmosis can be used to create these smaller files, and that it can do so from either the POSTGIS database or the large .osm file directly. Can anyone advise which approach would be faster?